# Invert atoms from list to integers - Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, integer, atomic

I have this:

```
streams=[[1,2,2,4],[2,1,4,2],[3,4,1,3],[4,3,3,1]]
```

And the numbers inside that lists are all atoms and I need to invert then all to integers. The streams should look like this:

```
streams=[[1,2,2,4],[2,1,4,2],[3,4,1,3],[4,3,3,1]]
```

But with all numbers with format 'integer' and not 'atom'
Can someone explain how tranform those numbers to integers please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert between atom and number you can use the built-in predicate [atom_number/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_number/2):

```
?- atom_number(Atom, 1).
Atom = '1'.

?- atom_number('1', Number).
Number = 1.
```

Using [maplist/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3), you can apply that convertion on all elements of a *list of atoms*:

```
?- maplist(atom_number, ['1','2','2','3'], Numbers).
Numbers = [1, 2, 2, 3].
```

To apply that convertion on all atoms in a *list of lists* you can do as follows:

```
?- maplist(maplist(atom_number), [['1','2'],['2','1','4'],['3'],['4','1']], ListOfLists).
ListOfLists = [[1, 2], [2, 1, 4], [3], [4, 1]].
```